# python: getting functions of instances of class from list via autocompletion

Tags: python, list, function, class, autocomplete

From a class called heatnet I like to return instance A stored in list[0].
In the Main file I like to call all functions that are related to the instance. This functions shall be shown from the autocomplete by spyder or PyCharm. Tried rope, jedi etc. The run works but not the autocomplete at writing.

```
from Pipe import Pipe

class Heatnet(object):

    def __init__(self, iteminstance):
        print(iteminstance)
        self.list = []
        self.list.append(Pipe(iteminstance[0], iteminstance[1]))

    def pipes(self, i = slice(None, None)):
        return self.list[i]

class Pipe:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y

heatnet.pipes(0).area()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: 
Dont make list of instances private. If it is protected or public autocompletion works properly.